# Chaining java methods game

Tags: java, methods, processing

I have a class with few methods (for sake of simplicity i added only two here), and i am using chaining to set the questions on the object question. When i use the method the only once it works fine, however when i use the same methods a multiple times it removes the data entered in the first method and only prints the last data entered. I want to chain them as they are in the example but not overwrite the data in the method. How do i do that?

```
class Questions {
    String quesNum, qTitle;
    int xPos, yPos;

    Questions(){}

    public Quiz questionTitle(String qN, String qT){
       this.quesNum = qN;
       this.quesTitle = qT;
       return this; 
    }
    public Quiz questionPosition(int x, int y){
    this.xPos = x;
    this.yPos = y;
}

Questions question;

void setup() {
size(600, 600);
question = new Quesion(); 
}
// loops
void draw() {
    question.questionTitle("Q1", "What is your name?")
            .questionPosition(100, 100)
            .questionTitle("Q2", "What is your height?")
            .questionPosition(100, 200)
            .questionTitle("Q3", "What is your weight?")
            .questionPosition(100, 300);
}
```

Comment: You're posting code with sloppy errors making it hard for us to understand your problem. Please post real code. Please check first for errors.

Comment: So you want some questionable beauty of the language that you do not understand?.. Calling the method for the second time (either chaining or not) does exactly what the method is defined to do: in your case reset some values... (downvote from me)

Comment: There is only one `Question` so yes you overwrite `xPos` etc What do you expect?

Comment: `questionPosition` needs to return `this`... also... do you want different questions; or to keep updating the same one.

Comment: Why exactly you want to do this with method chaining?

Comment: I guess i didn't explained good enough. I would like to have different questions using the same method, rather then updating the same one, but to be done with chaining. Btw the tags also say processing.

Comment: Your code still is bad. How can your constructor have a different name from the class? Again, *please* check and eliminate sloppy errors. You can't be careless when you code -- neither should you be when asking coding questions.

Comment: I figured it out, sorry for the hasty written code.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return the instance :

```
public Quiz questionPosition(int x, int y) {
    this.xPos = x;
    this.yPos = y;
}
```

Should be :

```
public Quiz questionPosition(int x, int y) {
    this.xPos = x;
    this.yPos = y;
    return this;
}
```

In addition, calling the same method multiple times overwrites the member values of your object.